# Parsing XML using the xpath.js in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, xpath

My XML looks like this:

```
<ns2:OrderList>
  <order order_id="123" item_name="123"/>
  <order order_id="234" item_name="1233"/>
  <order order_id="2357" item_name="1234"/>
  ......
</ns2:OrderList>
```

I am wanting to use the [XPath.js from npjms](https://www.npmjs.org/package/xpath.js).
How can I get array with "order_id" values ????

Comment: Probably you know how to use jQuery. Consider using Cheerio https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick if you want to use xpath.js (you also need xmldom for parsing though).

```
const Dom = require('xmldom').DOMParser;
const select = require('xpath.js');
const xml = '<ns2:OrderList> <order order_id="123" item_name="123"/> <order order_id="234" item_name="1233"/> <order order_id="2357" item_name="1234"/> </ns2:OrderList>¬';
const doc = new Dom().parseFromString(xml);
const nodes = select(doc, '//order');

const orderIds = nodes.map((node) => node.getAttribute('order_id'));
console.log(orderIds);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var select = require('xpath.js')
    , dom = require('xmldom').DOMParser

var xml = `<ns2:OrderList>
            <order order_id="123" item_name="123"/>
            <order order_id="234" item_name="1233"/>
            <order order_id="2357" item_name="1234"/>
           </ns2:OrderList>`;


var doc = new dom().parseFromString(xml);    
var nodes = select(doc, "//order/@order_id");
var orderIds = [];
nodes.forEach(function(node) {
    orderIds.push(node.nodeValue);
});

console.log(orderIds);
```